# How do I detect reboot/shutdown from a linux driver

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, reboot

I have a loadable linux module which controls some hardware.  I need to run some code before a soft reboot, however, I noticed the module destructor does not seem to be called in this situation, so I'm wondering how to have the driver informed before the reboot occurs.

Answer (score 4):

You want [`register_reboot_notifier()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/reboot.c#L89). For an example you can look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130523010400/http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/drivers/watchdog/softdog.c): see lines 181, 142, 129.